# OGR2OGR workaround for gpx-json conversion bug

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, gpx

ogr2ogr produces invalid GeoJSON when multiple layers are involved (http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/ticket/3842). For example:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON "$f.json" "$f" tracks routes
```

For me the bad GeoJSON seems to be a missing "] }" at the end of the file, but I don't know if that's consistent.

I'm trying to batch convert a number of GPX files. Some have tracks, some have routes; none have both. Is there a workaround that will work on both types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, here a WORKAROUND, which works for me in Bash. It first counts the features in the layers, then uses the resulting list of non-empty layers for further processing.

```
for file in *.gpx ; do 
    for layer in routes tracks ; do 
        echo -n "$file $layer " &&
        ogr2ogr -f csv /dev/stdout $file -sql "select count(*) from $layer" |
        awk 'NR>1'
    done
done | awk '$3' |
while read f l j ; do ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON "${f%.gpx}_$l.json" "$f" $l ; done
```

Comment: Thanks very much! It works, with two caveats. 1) GPX files with spaces in the name break something (maybe awk), 2) Since I don't care about the distinction between tracks and routes, I remove the `_$l`.

Comment: Indeed: you'd have to take care about spaces in file names. My file names never have spaces, so I forget to worry about potential pitfalls.